# Access variable in ViewController from a different class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, class

I have a slider `sliderLineSize` and a variable `lineSize` in a ViewController. The UISlider `sliderLineSize` changes `lineSize`. However, `lineSize` actually used in the `drawRect` section of the `viewLine` class which attaches to a UIView.

**Question:**

**How do I pass or make accessible the variable `lineSize` which is set in the ViewController to the class `viewLine` where it is used in `drawRect`?**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!

    var lineSize: Int = 1

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        myImageView.alpha = 0.5
    }

    @IBAction func sliderLineSize(sender: UISlider) {
        lineSize = Int(sender.value)
    }

}

class viewLine: UIView {

    let path=UIBezierPath()
    var incrementalImage:UIImage?
    var previousPoint:CGPoint = CGPoint.zero
    var strokeColor:UIColor?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
            incrementalImage?.drawInRect(rect)
            path.lineWidth = lineSize
            path.stroke()
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch: AnyObject? = touches.first
        let currentPoint = touch!.locationInView(self)
        path.moveToPoint(currentPoint)
        previousPoint=currentPoint
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch: AnyObject? = touches.first
        let currentPoint = touch!.locationInView(self)
        let midPoint = self.midPoint(previousPoint, p1: currentPoint)
        path.addQuadCurveToPoint(midPoint,controlPoint: previousPoint)
        previousPoint=currentPoint
        path.moveToPoint(midPoint)
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        self.drawBitmap()
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
        path.removeAllPoints()
    }

    func midPoint(p0:CGPoint,p1:CGPoint)->CGPoint {
        let x=(p0.x+p1.x)/2
        let y=(p0.y+p1.y)/2
        return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    }

    func drawBitmap() {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, true, 1)
        strokeColor?.setStroke()
        if((incrementalImage) == nil){
            let rectPath:UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds)
            UIColor.whiteColor().setFill()
            rectPath.fill()
        }
        incrementalImage?.drawAtPoint(CGPointZero)
        path.stroke()
        incrementalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }

}
```

Comment: Your ViewController doesn't have the reference of viewLine or isn't any of your View in ViewController Interface Builder has class set to ViewLine?

Comment: Does `ViewController`'s view contain a `viewLine` subview which you want to change the `lineWidth` of or is the `viewLine` owned by some other view controller?

Comment: Yes, viewLine class is attached to a UIView inside the ViewController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main ways to do this.

### Option 1:

Give your `ViewLine` class its own `lineSize` property:

```
class ViewLine: UIView {
    var lineSize = 1
}
```

Give `ViewController` a reference to `ViewLine`, and use a property observer to update the property inside `viewLine` whenever it changes in `ViewController`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // v~~~ be sure to connect this outlet in interface builder
    @IBOutlet weak var viewLine: ViewLine!
   
    var lineSize = 1 {
        didSet {
            viewLine.lineSize = lineSize
        }
    }
}
```

Now your `ViewLine` class will have its own `lineSize` property that can be accessed from within its `drawRect` method directly.

### Option 2:

Give your `ViewLine` class a reference to `ViewController`:

```
class ViewLine: UIView {

    // v~~~ be sure to connect this outlet in interface builder
    @IBOutlet weak var controller: ViewController!
}
```

Now, in your `drawRect` method, replace `path.lineWidth = lineSize` with `path.lineWidth = controller.lineSize`.

Basically, one of your classes needs a reference to the other in order for them to be able to communicate.

Comment: Another option is to send messages via the responder chain... this allows for loose coupling.

Comment: or perhaps this is really an app setting--in which case you could use NSUserDefaults + a known key

Comment: Thanks. I prefer option 2 for its ultra simple implementation, it works well.

Comment: Hi, how can i hide `UIButton` from `UIViewcontroller` class, `UIButton` is declare on `CustomView` class?

Answer (score 1):

You should make Singleton Model class. A singleton class can be accessed from anywhere. Here is how you should create a singleton class in swift.

```
class ApplicationModel {

    class var sharedInstance: ApplicationModel {
        get {
            struct Static {
                static var instance: ApplicationModel? = nil
                static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
            }
            dispatch_once(&Static.token, {
                Static.instance = ApplicationModel()
            })
            return Static.instance!
        }
    }

    var lineSize = 1
}
```

Inside ViewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Instantiate ApplicationModel
        //GET
        let lineSize = ApplicationModel.sharedInstance.lineSize

        //SET
        ApplicationModel.sharedInstance.lineSize = 5
    }
```

Inside viewLine

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

     //Access Application Model


            //GET
            let lineSize = ApplicationModel.sharedInstance.lineSize

            //SET
            ApplicationModel.sharedInstance.lineSize = 5
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works but I don't think it is a good solution. This is just introducing a global and allowing implicit coupling between every class which accesses it. While you absolutely can make an app work that way I think developers are better served by deliberately modeling the communication interfaces and dependencies between classes.

Comment: Not entirely agree with you. But yes improvement scope is there.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting approach, but option 2 in the accepted answer is a more streamlined solution.